# Laravel storage path in production server

Tags: laravel, path, storage

I do have a trouble to save generated excel file in the production server, I did set the storage path in `/public/reports` directory as like below:

```
$filename = "report-".date('YmdHis').".xlsx";
$storage_path = public_path('reports');
```

However, the file wouldn't be saved in `reports` folder but at the `public` folder, I've been tried

```
$storage_path = public_path().'\reports\\';
```

but this will save outside of the public folder.

I'm new in laravel, I appreciate if anyone can point out what is the workaround.

**Edit**

Here is the whole block:

```
public function handle()
{
    $spreadsheet = new Spreadsheet();

    $sheet = $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet();
    $sheet->getStyle('C')->getAlignment()->setHorizontal('left');
    $sheet->getColumnDimension('A')->setWidth(8);
    $sheet->getColumnDimension('B')->setWidth(30);
    $sheet->setCellValue('A1', 'title');
    $sheet->setCellValue('B1', 'brief');

    $reports = Report::get();
    if(count($reports) > 0) {
        $rowCount = 2;
        foreach($reports as $report) {
            $sheet->setCellValue('A' . $rowCount, $report->title);
            $sheet->setCellValue('B' . $rowCount, $report->brief);
            $rowCount++;
        }
    }

    $spreadsheet->getActiveSheet()->setTitle('Report Title');
    $spreadsheet->setActiveSheetIndex(0);

    $export_filename = "report-".date('YmdHis').".xlsx";
    \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage::disk('reports')->put($export_filename, $content);

    $writer = new Xlsx($spreadsheet);
    $writer->save($storage_path.$export_filename);

    Mail::to(env('RPT_RECEIVER'))->send(new ReportsMail($storage_path.$export_filename, 'Report Name', date('F')));
    exit;
}
```

Comment: Can you provide the whole code? How exactly do you save the generated excel file?

Comment: Please check my answer below

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The right way to do it in Laravel is save it in the `storage` directory.

Seems that you're using the PHPSpreadsheet library.

I suggest use this code to save the excel file:

```
    $export_filename = "report-".date('YmdHis').".xlsx";

    $writer = new Xlsx($spreadsheet);
    $writer->save(storage_path("app/public/{$export_filename}));

    Mail::to(env('RPT_RECEIVER'))->send(new ReportsMail($storage_path.$export_filename, 'Report Name', date('F')));
    exit;
```

The code above wiill save the excel file inside `storage/app/public`

Then in order for the file to be accessible in public, run the command: `php artisan storage:link`. This will create a symlink (or shortcut) `storage` inside your `public` directory.

In order to access the file use this code:

```
    $file_url = asset('storage/sample.xlsx');
```

REMEMBER, to run also the `php artisan storage:link` to the production server.

Answer (score 0):

In congif/filesystem.php file add this after "local" => [],

```
'reports' => [
            'driver' => 'local',
            'root' => public_path().'/reports'
        ],
```

then use this code

```
$filename = "report-".date('YmdHis').".xlsx";
    \Illuminate\Support\Facades\Storage::disk('reports')->put($filename, $content);
```

Comment: @TheGrimmer, well you have to assign the variable `$content`, that will contain the value of the excel file. Please provide us your whole code in order for us to help you further.

Comment: @aceraven777 I edited the post to put a whole code, can u help?

Comment: Which package do you using for excel?

Comment: try this. replace $content to $writer